# CAShapeLayer fill color will stay White

Tags: swift, uiview, cashapelayer

I can clearly see my line, with the right stroke color, and the line is being drawn correctly, but no matter what, the fill color stay white.

I have added this layer to another `UIView` subclass (custom view )

```
  let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.frame=CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (size?.width)!, height: size!.height)
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath //from my bezier path
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = curveLineColor!.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
    shapeLayer.lineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.round
    shapeLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
    self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

What else can I try ?

**EDIT**

here is how I create the path :

```
 let path = UIBezierPath()
 var point1:CGPoint!
 var point2:CGPoint!
 var firstpoint:CGPoint!

 for i in 0..<curvePoints.count-1
 {
    point1 = curvePoints[i]
    point2 = curvePoints[i+1]

    point1.y=size!.height-point1.y
    point2.y=size!.height-point2.y


    path.move(to: point1)
    path.addLine(to: point2)

    if( i == 0 ) {firstpoint=point1}



 }

//close the path
path.move(to: point2)
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width, y: frame.height))
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width, y: frame.height))
path.addLine(to: firstpoint)

path.close()
```

Turns out if you don't close your line it will not color it, but my line describes a time series and my look like this :

[image]

As you can see I close the curve from the bottom, **but**, because of those triangle are open I can not put color under this line. It works only if I put a line that close all those triangles.

Any suggestions to get a simple time series line filled with a color ?

Comment: Can you share the path creation code?

Comment: Yes I edit again, please check it , thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the `bezierPath`, the start `point` is getting shifted every time in the loop so `path.close()` is not able to `close` the `path` correctly w.r.t the start `point`. By removing unnecessary `move's`  it works fine as below,

```
let path = UIBezierPath()

let curvePoints = [
    CGPoint.init(x: 60, y: 280),
    CGPoint.init(x: 100, y: 60),
    CGPoint.init(x: 150, y: 200),
    CGPoint.init(x: 220, y: 100),
    CGPoint.init(x: 300, y: 280)
]
path.move(to: curvePoints.first!)

for i in 1..<curvePoints.count {
    path.addLine(to: curvePoints[i])
}
path.close()

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
shapeLayer.lineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.round // OR kCALineJoinRound
shapeLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round // OR kCALineCapRound
self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I've never set the frame for a CAShapeLayer. From Apple's docs, "For layers, the frame rectangle is a computed property that is derived from the values in the bounds, anchorPoint and position properties.".

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out, you do not have to move the path to the new point every new line you make, it moves there automatically.

so removing `path.move(to: point2)` ,  solves the problem !
Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I didn't notice you already figured out the issue, still i updated my answer with the possible fix.